# Angular 7 TypeError: Cannot read pro

Tags: angular, error-handling

i make a front application with angular and i have one error in the front :

[image: error Screen]

error : index.js:3757 TypeError: Cannot read pro

I tried :

- inspect but i can't see the end of the error.
  [image]
- Ng build but the build success
- look in the console : nothing

I think this error is "Cannot read property of undefined"... but i need more informations.

```
    <div class="p-grid down-part">
  <div class="p-col-6 withoutAppointment">
    <div class="subtitle-container">
      <span class="container-title">Sans RDV</span>
      <div class="offers-counter"><span>{{projectsList['plan_call'].total }}</span> offres</div>
      <fa-icon class="reload-btn" [icon]="['fas','sync-alt']" (click)="reloadProjects('plan_call')"></fa-icon>

    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let project of projectsList['plan_call'].projects">

      <div *ngIf="project._estimation" class="content-row ">
        <div class=" city-col">
          <div class="option">
            <h2>{{getLocalisation(project)}}</h2>

            <div *ngIf="getLocalisation(project) == 'Paris'" class="option-corner-orange"></div>
            <div *ngIf="getLocalisation(project) == 'Paris'" class="option-corner-left-orange"></div>
            <div *ngIf="getLocalisation(project) == 'Bordeaux'" class="option-corner-blue"></div>
            <div *ngIf="getLocalisation(project) == 'Bordeaux'" class="option-corner-left-blue"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class=" content-col">
          <div class="dashboard-management-content-title" (click)="navigateToProjectDetails(project)">
            <span *ngIf="getProjectOwner(project) !== undefined">
              {{getProjectOwner(project)._user.name}}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="dashboard-management-content-subtitle">
            <div class="label-1">{{getObjective(project)}} {{getProperty(project)}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="load-more-container">
      <p-button class="load-more" label="Charger plus de projets" (click)="loadMoreProjects('plan_call')"></p-button>
    </div>
  </div>index.js:3757 TypeError: Cannot read pro

  <div class="p-col-6 waitForPj">
    <div class="subtitle-container">
      <span class="container-title">En attente de PJ</span>
      <div class="offers-counter"><span>{{projectsList['docs_needed'].total }}</span> offres</div>

    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let project of projectsList['docs_needed'].projects">

      <div *ngIf="project._estimation" class="content-row">
        <div class=" city-col">
          <div class="option">
            <h2>{{getLocalisation(project)}}</h2>

            <div *ngIf="getLocalisation(project) == 'Paris'" class="option-corner-orange"></div>
            <div *ngIf="getLocalisation(project) == 'Paris'" class="option-corner-left-orange"></div>
            <div *ngIf="getLocalisation(project) == 'Bordeaux'" class="option-corner-blue"></div>
            <div *ngIf="getLocalisation(project) == 'Bordeaux'" class="option-corner-left-blue"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content-col">
          <div class="dashboard-management-content-title" (click)="navigateToProjectDetails(project)">
            <span *ngIf="getProjectOwner(project) !== undefined">
              {{getProjectOwner(project)._user.name}}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="dashboard-management-content-subtitle">
            <div class="label-1">{{getObjective(project)}} {{getProperty(project)}}</div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="load-more-container">
      <p-button class="load-more" label="Charger plus de projets" (click)="loadMoreProjects('docs_needed')"></p-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your errors as text, and provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: This error dosn't appear in the console or the build i have only : index.js:3757 TypeError: Cannot read pro

Comment: If it's displayed, then you can probably copy and paste it. Currently, on my side, I can't go on imgur because of corporate proxies. If you don't post your error, I can't see it, and I can't help you (and currently it seems I'm the only one willing to do it). Up to you !

Comment: I put the error, but like i said, i can't really see any words afters "pro"

Comment: And where is this error coming from exactly ?

Comment: if you right click on the text and do inspect, you might be able to find and copy the full error message

Comment: @mast3rd3mon like i said, i already tried, i add a  screen to show you

Comment: @trichetriche idk that's the problem..

Comment: @BenjaminBarbé where is it displayed ?

Comment: can you post the code for that page? specifically the code between the `p-grid down-part` and `p-col-6 waitForPj` div's?

Comment: @trichetriche in the navigator only

Comment: @mast3rd3mon post updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not an error, you can see in the code/HTML that you have posted that the error is literally written in your code/HTML:

```
</div>index.js:3757 TypeError: Cannot read pro
<div class="p-col-6 waitForPj">
```

That explains why the message doesn't display fully and why you don't actually receive any error in the console

Comment: no problem, i did find it odd that it showed the message that it did in the HTML and not the console